# Customers that have not bought in 6 months and have no outstanding sales orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the task of finding out which of our customers have not bought from us in 6 months and have no outstanding sales orders.

The information is contained in two tables:
customers and sales

The customer number is common to both tables and I need to pull the customer number and name
the customer table has a invoice date so i could look for that and the sales table has a status column that includes closed and open status's and a date printed column.

I am sure this is all I would need to put it together but am stumped as to how.

Sorry, I guess i did not explain myself very well. 
I know would write something like.

```
Select Distinct I.Customer,
  I.InvoiceToName
From
  tblarInvoice I
  Inner Join tblsoSO S 
  On I.CustomerShipTo = S.CustomerShipTo   

  Where max(I.dateprinted) <= '06/01/2013' 
  or max(S.dateordered) <= '06/01/2013' 
  and S.status = 'closed'
```

the above would not work as I think I would get every record back to the beginning of time and I just need those that have not ordered in the last 6 months. not to mention the problem with an aggregate in the Where statement. Which I know does not work but do not know how to make work even if it was what I wanted.

So I am stumped as to what to use to get the no orders for 6 months back.

Comment: Have you tried forming a query? If so, can you post that query so that we can further help?

Comment: After reading your requirements again I want to check; you need "...which of our customers have not bought from us in 6 months and have no outstanding sales orders." - Does this mean you can have a customer who ordered over 6 months ago and the order is still "open"?

Comment: Correct, this would be a customer that placed a blanket order that could go back as much as a year. This is why I am checking the S.status. If S.status is open then I do not want to include the customer in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Do a little "thinking in sets" and that should help you on your way to building some queries.

You have a set of `customers` and a set of `sales`. The intersection of these are the `customers` who have bought products from you; join these tables to find out who they are.

Another requirement is that they have 'no outstanding orders'. You said the `status` field tells you if the order is "open" so this will form part of your `WHERE` clause to filter the sales rows.

See if that gets you started, try something out, and if you get stuck post the query and ask for help about a specific problem. At the moment you are just asking people to write the query for you :)

**EDIT:**

Looking at the query you have added there are some inconsistencies in what you originally said.

You mentioned `Customer` and `Sales` tables but you are using `tblarInvoice` (Invoice?) `tblsoSO` (Sales_Order?). I'm going to simplify the problem and assume all the information about an order is in one table `Sales_Order`; you can modify the queries to use the actual tables you have.

You need to define what "not ordered in the last 6 months" actually means. You have two fields with dates; I'm going to assume `date_ordered` has to be more than 6 months ago and ignore `dateprinted` as that sounds like something that happens later.

We can make use of `DATEDIFF` to deduct 6 months from the current date, so whenever you run the query you will get a "rolling" last 6 months:

```
SELECT  customer
FROM    Sales_Order
WHERE   date_ordered <= DATEADD(month, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

You also want a set of customers that excludes anyone with "open" orders:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        SO1.customer
FROM    ( SELECT    customer
          FROM      Sales_Order
          WHERE     order_status = 'closed'
        ) SO1
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  customer
                    FROM    Sales_Order
                    WHERE   order_status = 'open'
                  ) SO2 ON SO1.customer = SO2.customer
WHERE   SO2.customer IS NULL
```

Now combine that with the set of customers who have not ordered in the last 6 months.
BTW I'm not suggesting this is the *best* way to write the query, I'm just trying to make it easy to understand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        SO1.customer
FROM    ( SELECT    customer
                   ,date_ordered
          FROM      Sales_Order
          WHERE     order_status = 'closed'
        ) SO1
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  customer
                    FROM    Sales_Order
                    WHERE   order_status = 'open'
                  ) SO2 ON SO1.customer = SO2.customer
WHERE   SO2.customer IS NULL
        AND date_ordered <= DATEADD(month, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I added my query to my original post. @jO3z